# PHP not updating MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and want to create a script that will update the users first and last name if they need to do so. I have the code below and it ends up echoing out `UPDATE fixableusers SET first='trenton' WHERE id='6'` on the settings.inc.php page but it is not updating the table. Is there a reason it is not updating the table?

```
<?php
include_once('dbh.php');

session_start();
$userSession = $_SESSION['id'];

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $postTest = $_POST['first'];
    $sql = "UPDATE fixableusers SET first='$postTest' WHERE id='$userSession'";
} else {
    echo 'Do something else';
}
```

My dbh.php file includes the following code:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'users');
```

Comment: what do you have in dbh.php ?

Comment: 'WHERE id='$userSession'";' dosnt exist in the db yet

Comment: did you execute that query?

Comment: you are not executing the sql query and do u select a db?

Comment: please use prepared statements to fix your sql injection vunlerability ( malicious things passed in post ).  There's no point in _not_ making a good habit starting _now_.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are excluding the mysqli_query function,

Add this `mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` after build the `$sql`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your if statement you're just declaring variables, in order to actually execute a query you need to : 
`if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $postTest = $_POST['first'];
    $sql = "UPDATE fixableusers SET first='$postTest' WHERE id='$userSession'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}`

And you need to improve this ( handle errors ..etc)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Connect your DB
include_once('dbh.php');

//Start Session    
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

// Update Query
$updateqry = "UPDATE fixableusers SET first='".$_POST['first']."' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
mysqli_query($conn, $updateqry);

} else {

        echo 'Do something else';
}

?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code so the OP and further readers can understand your code. The OP is a beginner and so are many others on this site.